Django - Removing subdomains from my multitenancy app
I have a working multitenancy app in Django with isolated databases that currently uses a subdomain for each tenant and threading. The subdomain prefix is used to make a connection to the corresponding database, so:

client1.mysite.com access the database client1
client2.mysite.com access the database client2

And so on. This is the current code I have:
middleware:
import threading

from app.utils import tenant_db_from_the_request

Thread_Local = threading.local()


class AppMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        db = tenant_db_from_the_request(request)
        setattr(Thread_Local, 'DB', db)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


def get_current_db_name():
    return getattr(Thread_Local, 'DB', None)

utils:
def hostname_from_the_request(request):
    return request.get_host().split(':')[0].lower()


def tenant_db_from_the_request(request):
    hostname = hostname_from_the_request(request)
    tenants_map = get_tenants_map()
    return tenants_map.get(hostname)


def get_tenants_map():
    return dict(Tenants.objects.values_list('subdomain', 'database',))

routers:
class AppRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return get_current_db_name()

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return get_current_db_name()

    def allow_relation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None

Using subdomains is not exactly ideal, so I'm trying to switch the subdomain prefix to a suffix that will be added to the username of each user in the tenant. With that, every user will access the same URL:
mysite.com
And the suffix will be added to the username like that:

user@client1 access the database client1
user@client2 access the database client2

Since I already have this working with subdomain, my thought process is to change just the middleware to retrieve the suffix of the username and use session to store the tenant alias that will be used on each database request. With that in mind, I changed just my utils file to this:
def hostname_from_the_request(request):
    # changed the request to get the 'db_alias' from the session
    return request.session.get('db_alias', None)


def get_tenants_map():
    # change the mapping to retrieve the database based on a alias, instead of subddomain
    return dict(Tenants.objects.values_list('alias', 'database',))

And added the 3 lines of code before the authentication process in my login view:
if request.method == "POST":

    if form.is_valid():

        # retrieve the alias from the username
        complete_username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        db_alias = complete_username.split('@')[1]
        request.session['db_alias'] = db_alias

        user = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
            password=form.cleaned_data.get('password'),
        )

This works, but only after the second login attempt. The first one always return a failed authentication error. At first I thought that this was because the session was being created only after the failed login attempt, but with print statements and breakpoints I can confirm that this is not the case. The session is being created before the authentication and the name of the database is being retrieved correctly (the name retrieval is correct because after the second attempt, the login is successful and each request is processed on the corresponding database).
I've tried to change the middleware settings and put the AppMiddleware right after the session middleware (before, it was the last on the list), but with no change.
I also tried to use the session data directly instead of threading, but the problem with that is that the router doesn't accept a request parameter, or at least it is what I understood from the docs, but I could be wrong.
I'm not very skilled in Python / Django so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Or maybe this is the wrong way to achieve what I want. So, I'm missing something? How can i make this work with the first login attempt?

I have rewritten the entire middleware and changed its logic. I completely stopped using the DomainModel database from django-tenants, which has become redundant in my case.
I started using cookie-based authentication, where the middleware automatically adds the schema name to the server-side cookie for authenticated users.
I also completely stopped using the context_tenant method from django_tenant because it simply didn't respond at all. I replaced it with self.connection.set_schema(schema_name), which works very well in my case.
In the middleware, I fetch the user's cookie ID, decode it, and filter the corresponding record from the UserModel database, where I now store the schema_name. This schema_name is then used to switch the database schema.
If the authentication cookie doesn't exist, the middleware automatically sets the schema to "public" and checks if a cookie named "tenant_id" exists on the server. If the user is not authenticated and this cookie exists, the middleware deletes it.
Since switching the schema loses access to the public schema where the cookie data is stored, I had to rewrite the session backend logic to always look for cookie data in the public schema. This centralizes cookie handling in the "public" schema.
Currently, the application maintains the switched schema_name for authenticated users, which allows me to switch schemas based on user authentication. Therefore, I don't need to use subdomains or other URL prefixes.
I'm not sure if this approach is ideal, as I am relatively new to this, but the application works, which made me quite happy after a week of reading. :D I hope this tip helps you, and thank you for your feedback.

I'm glad you figured it out! If you can, please post the code you used. It is a different approach to using isolated databases, but maybe your code can help me to achieve what I want.

Middleware
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
from django.db import connection
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SessionStore(DBStore):
    def get_model_class(self):
        from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
        return Session

    def save(self, must_create=False):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before saving session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            super(SessionStore, self).save(must_create)

    def load(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before loading session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            return super(SessionStore, self).load()

Shared_session_backend
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
from django.db import connection
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SessionStore(DBStore):
    def get_model_class(self):
        from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
        return Session

    def save(self, must_create=False):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before saving session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            super(SessionStore, self).save(must_create)

    def load(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before loading session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            return super(SessionStore, self).load()


To make it work, you need to add the schema_name field to the UserModel.

SHARED_SESSION BACKEND
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
from django.db import connection
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SessionStore(DBStore):
    def get_model_class(self):
        from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
        return Session

    def save(self, must_create=False):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before saving session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            super(SessionStore, self).save(must_create)

    def load(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            logger.debug("Setting search_path to public before loading session")
            cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public")
            return super(SessionStore, self).load()

SHARED_SESSION_BACKEND
import logging

from django.http import Http404
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.db import connection
from tenants_app.models import TenantModel
from authorization_app.models import UserModel


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CookieTenantMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        super().__init__(get_response)
        self.get_response = get_response
        logger.debug("CookieTenantMiddleware initialized")

    def set_connection_schema(self, schema_name):
        connection.set_schema(schema_name)
        logger.debug(f"Schema set to: {schema_name}")

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get("session_cookie")
        logger.debug(f"Session key: {session_key}")
        print(f"Session key: {session_key}")

        if session_key:
            try:
                session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
                print(f"Session: {session}")
                session_user_id = session.get_decoded().get("_auth_user_id")
                print(f"USER ID: {session_user_id}")
                logger.debug(f"Session user ID: {session_user_id}")

                if session_user_id:
                    usermodel_instance = UserModel.objects.get(pk=session_user_id)
                    print(f"UserModel instance: {usermodel_instance.pk}")
                    print(f"User schemay_name {usermodel_instance.schema_name}")
                    #tenant_instance = TenantModel.objects.get(owner_id=usermodel_instance.pk)
                    #print(f"Tenant_instance: {tenant_instance}")

                    #NASTAVENÍ COOKIE S TENANT_ID
                    #if "tenant_id" not in request.session:
                    #    request.session["tenant_id"] = usermodel_instance.schema_name
                    #načtení nově uložené cookie
                    #tenant_id = request.session.get("tenant_id")

                    self.set_connection_schema(usermodel_instance.schema_name)
                    print(f"Connection schema: {connection.schema_name}")
                    request.schema_name = usermodel_instance.schema_name
                    #logger.debug(f"Tenant instance: {tenant_instance}")
                else:
                    logger.error("User not authenticated")
                    raise Http404("User not authenticated")
            except Session.DoesNotExist:
                logger.error("Session does not exist")
                self.set_public_schema()
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                logger.error("User does not exist")
                self.set_public_schema()
            except TenantModel.DoesNotExist:
                logger.error("Tenant does not exist")
                self.set_public_schema()
        else:
            logger.debug("No session key found, setting public schema")
            self.set_public_schema()

    def set_public_schema(self):
        try:
            public_schema = TenantModel.objects.get(schema_name="public")
            print(public_schema)
            self.set_connection_schema(public_schema.schema_name)
            print(f"Public: {connection.schema_name}")

            #if 'tenant_id' in request.session:
             #   del request.session['tenant_id']

            logger.debug(f"Set schema to public: {public_schema.schema_name}")
        except TenantModel.DoesNotExist:
            logger.error("Public schema not found")
            raise Http404("Public schema not found")

To make it work, you need to add the schema_name field to the UserModel.
